# Excel Type Provider Error

Tags: excel, f#, type-providers

I have tried to use the Excel Type Provider located [here](http://fsprojects.github.io/ExcelProvider/) but it seems to throw the following error?

> Referenced assembly 'C:\Projects2012\DBA
>   Projects\CustomerCountAnalysis\CustomerCountAnalysis../packages/ExcelProvider/lib/ExcelProvider.dll'
>   has assembly level attribute
>   'Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerServices.TypeProviderAssemblyAttribute'
>   but no public type provider classes were found

Is there any way to fix this? Full screenshot of the error in Visual Studio can be seen below:

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem using FCS 23.0.3 and Excel provider 0.8.2